# gprolog difference list with duplicate

Tags: prolog

i have to get list difference between two integer list (both ordinate).
i white this:

```
difference(L,[],L) :- !.
difference([],_,[]) :- !.
difference([],[],W). 
difference([H|T1],[D|T2],T3) :- difference(T1,[D|T2],[H|T3]).
difference([H|T1],[H|T2],T3) :- difference(T1,T2,T3).
```

but why i can't get my list difference?
if i write this:

```
difference([],[],W):- write(X).
```

and this example:

```
| ?- difference([1,4,4],[1,4],R).    
[4|_27]
```

it makes right!
NB if i have duplicate number i have to show it!

Comment: `([],_,[])` `(L,[],L)` All I see are Kirby faces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your code rather odd. For instance, your third clause: what's `W` for? Seems like you mean to say:

```
difference([],[],_).
```

Second problem: in the fourth clause, there's nothing stopping H and D from being independent variables with the same binding. I suspect you mean something like this:

```
difference([H|T1],[D|T2],T3) :- H \= D, difference(T1,[D|T2],[H|T3]).
```

Fixing these things seems to fix the predicate to give a reasonable looking answer:

```
| ?- difference([1,4,4], [1,4], R).
R = [4]
```

I think your first several clauses are trying to handle different sorts of base cases, is that right? E.g.:

```
difference(L, [], L)   % handles the case where the second list is exhausted
difference([], _, [])  % handles the case where the first list is exhausted
difference([], [], W)  % handles the case where the lists are exhausted at the same time
```

One problem with this is that L = [] is a legitimate binding, so the first and third clauses mean the same thing. You can probably safely remove the third one, because it would have matched and produced the same answer on the first. The second clause is more interesting, because it seems to say that regardless of whatever work we've done so far, if the first list is empty, the result is empty. I find that possibility a bit jarring--is it possible you actually want these two base cases? :

```
difference([], L, L).
difference(L, [], L).
```

I remain unconvinced, but until I have a better idea what you're trying to accomplish I may not be able to help more. For instance, what should happen with `difference([1, 4], [1, 4, 4], R)`? I posit you probably want `R = [4]`, but your code will produce `R = []`.

Also, I find it unlikely that

```
difference([],[],W):- write(X).
```

is going to be a helpful debugging strategy, because Prolog will generate a new variable binding for X because there's nothing for it to refer to.

The final version I have with all my changes looks like this:

```
difference(L, [], L) :- !.
difference([], L, L) :- !.
difference([H|T1], [D|T2], T3) :- D \= H, difference(T1, [D|T2], [H|T3]).
difference([H|T1], [H|T2], T3) :- difference(T1, T2, T3).
```

**Edit**: does this implement your requirements?

```
not_in1(X, Left, Right) :- member(X, Left), \+ member(X, Right).

not_in(X, Left, Right) :- not_in1(X, Left, Right).
not_in(X, Left, Right) :- not_in1(X, Right, Left).

differences(Left, Right, Differences) :-
    findall(X, not_in(X, Left, Right), Differences).


?- differences([1,2,3,4], [1,3,5], X).
X = [2,4,5]
```

If so, I'll try to get your original code to produce answers that match.

**Edit 2**: OK, so the problem with the solution above is that it is O(N^2). In the worst case (two totally distinct lists) it will have to compare every item from list 1 to every item of list 2. It's not exploiting the fact that both lists are ordered (I believe that's what you mean by 'ordinate').

The result looks a lot more like your original code, but your original code is not taking advantage of the fact that the items are ordered. This is why the fourth and fifth cases are confusing looking: you should recur down one of the lists or the other depending on which number is larger. The corrected code looks like this:

```
differences([], Result, Result).
differences(Result, [], Result).
differences([H|Ls], [H|Rs], Result) :- differences(Ls, Rs, Result).
differences([L|Ls], [R|Rs], [L|Result]) :-
    L < R,
    differences(Ls, [R|Rs], Result).
differences([L|Ls], [R|Rs], [R|Result]) :-
    L > R,
    differences([L|Ls], Rs, Result).
```

You can see this produces the same result as the O(N^2) method:

```
?- differences([1,2,3,4], [1,3,5], X).
X = [2,4,5]
```

You were right, you do need both base cases. This is so the remainder of either list becomes part of the result. Presumably these will be the largest values (`[5]` in the example).

Now I have three inductive cases: one for `<`, one for `>` and one for `=`. The equality case is intuitive: recur on both lists, discarding the head of both lists. The next case basically says if the left head is less than the right head, add it to the result and recur on the left's tail. The right is unchanged in that case. The other case is the mirror of this case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: if you test this exsample: difference([1,2,3,4],[1,3,4],R). you have to add difference([],[],_). the problem is that gprolog answers only "true" but i want get 2..

Comment: @fabio I've edited the answer--if that's the kind of solution you want, let me know and I'll see if I can find a way to get your code to produce it.

Comment: can i do a new question? how i can remove elements from list? example: remove(X,Toremove,R) where X, Toremove, R are list but if i do this: remove([2,1,2,4,3],[2], R will be only [2,1,4,3] and i don't remove all 2..thanks!

Comment: If you want to ask another question, use the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page, not a comment. Also, if this is homework, you need to tag the question that way so we know not to give you complete solutions.

Comment: @fabio Also, don't forget to click the check box to "accept" my answer if you are happy with it.

Comment: ops i found now a problem! differences([2,1,4,3],[1,2,3,4],R).

R = [1,1,3,3] !!! why?

Comment: Both your algorithm and mine assume the lists are already sorted.